# How to add repulsive forces to bodies in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am working on making a demo with circle bodies and want to apply repulsive forces on them so that they get their positions randomly on world. It should somewhat resemble like the planets in the universe. The placement(coordinates) of the bodies should depend on the forces that places them randomly.

Comment: This box2d tutorial can help you: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/03/28/simulate-radial-gravity-also-know-as-planet-gravity-with-box2d-as-seen-on-angry-birds-space/

Comment: To be specific, I want the nodes whose coordinates are not known to me and they disperse randomly because of repulsive forces applied on them.